# custom angular directive is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am trying to create a directive, but for some reason nothing is rendering.  The screen is blank.

index.html

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
         <program-listing listing="program"></program-listing>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/programListing.js"></script>
```

js/controllers/mainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.program = {
    series: "Sherlock",
    series_img: "img/sherlock.jpg",
    genre: "Crime drama",
    season: 3,
    episode: "The Empty Hearse",
    description: "Two years after his reported Reichenbach Fall demise, Sherlock, who has been cleared of all fraud charges against him, returns with Mycroft's help to a London under threat of terrorist attack. John has moved on and has a girlfriend, Mary Morstan. Sherlock enlists Molly to assist him, but when John is kidnapped by unknown assailants and is rescued by Sherlock and Mary, John returns to help find the terrorists and an underground plot to blow up the Houses of Parliament during an all night sitting on Guy Fawkes Night.",
    datetime: new Date(2014, 11, 31, 21, 00, 00, 00)
  };

}]);
```

js/directives/programListing.js

```
app.directive('programListing', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      listing: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/programListing.html'
  };
});
```

js/directives/programListing.html

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3" class="series_img">
      {{ listing.series_img }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1 class="series">{{listing.series}}</h1>
      <h2 class="episode">{{listing.episode}}</h2>
      <p class="description">{{listing.description}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Date:</span> {{listing.datetime | date:'mediumDate' }}  </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>On air:</span> {{ listing.datetime | date:'EEEE' }}  </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Time:</span>{{ listing.datetime | date:'shortTime' }}  </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Season:</span> {{listing.season}}  </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Genre:</span>{{ listing.genre }}  </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Why isn't anything rendering?

Comment: anything in dev console?

Comment: `templateUrl` is not part of scope btw..actually now that I think about it, that has to be your problem

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but the code still does not work.  I have updated the stackoverflow code to include your change.

Comment: Nothing appears in the dev console

Comment: Create a plunker or jsfiddle that reproduces the issue please.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code (although I removed templateUrl from scope and used template instead) and it worked fine. You should double check your console

Comment: Can I see the fiddle?

Comment: NVM, the answer below works.

Comment: lol so you mean my first comment worked ay? Thanks @PANDA Stack for stealing my answer!! Jk, have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

templateUrl is an argument to your directive. You should not have it in your scope. Your directive doesn't know what to render!

```
scope = {...},
templateUrl = '...'
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that and put the new code in the question above but it still does not work.

Comment: I had to change templateUrl = to templateUrl: but this was the issue.  thanks

Comment: @Philip7899 if you were in fact truly using your error console like you said you were, you would have seen that `=` didn't work in the first place